# Custom payment method with extra fee

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, payment-methods

I need to create a simple custom payment method like "cash on delivery" but with extra fee when customer selects it. I implemented payment method, but can't find how to make part with extra fee. Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: explain in more detail..  what do you mean by extra fee ?  if you want this payment method along or with existing one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2012/01/27/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total/) article how to add custom fee and only added couple changes to collect() function, like this:

```
public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
{
    parent::collect($address);
    try{
        $quote = $address->getQuote();
        $code = $quote->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
        if($code == 'my_payment'){
                $this->_setAmount(0);
                $this->_setBaseAmount(0);
                $items = $this->_getAddressItems($address);
                if (!count($items)) {
                    return $this; 
                }

                $exist_amount = $quote->getFeeAmount();
                //$fee = Excellence_Fee_Model_Fee::getFee(); 
                $fee=Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/my_payment/price');
                $balance = $fee - $exist_amount;
                $address->setFeeAmount($balance);
                $address->setBaseFeeAmount($balance);
                $quote->setFeeAmount($balance);
                $address->setGrandTotal($address->getGrandTotal() + $address->getFeeAmount());
                $address->setBaseGrandTotal($address->getBaseGrandTotal() + $address->getBaseFeeAmount());
        }
    } catch(Exception $e){}
}
```

Now only when user selects my payment method this fee would be added to totals

Comment: This is answer is for Magento1, Do you have the full code for Magento2 ?